# What problem does the StringBuilder solve?

Tags: c#, .net, string, stringbuilder, string-building

Why would I use a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) over simply appending strings?  For example why implement like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder;
sb.Append("A string");
sb.Append("Another string");
```

over

```
String first = "A string";
first += "Another string";
```

?

Comment: See http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html

Comment: It's a really memory efficient (with performance benefits) way of appending a large number of strings together without costing that many objects. (less objects ~ less time required by garbage collector)

Comment: Outside a loop it's not a big deal as the compiler will probably optimise that to `String first = "A stringAnother string";` one string. Everyone else seems to have covered the reasons not to use it in a loop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation of [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) explains its purpose:

> The String object is immutable. Every
>   time you use one of the methods in the
>   System.String class, you create a new
>   string object in memory, which
>   requires a new allocation of space for
>   that new object. In situations where
>   you need to perform repeated
>   modifications to a string, the
>   overhead associated with creating a
>   new String object can be costly. The
>   System.Text.StringBuilder class can be
>   used when you want to modify a string
>   without creating a new object. For
>   example, using the StringBuilder class
>   can boost performance when
>   concatenating many strings together in
>   a loop.

Answer (score 5):

In a simple case like yours, it really doesn't matter. But generally, strings are immutable, that means every change to a string variable will create a new buffer in memory, copy the new data and abandon the old buffer. In case you are doing a lot of string manipulation, this slows down your program and leads to a lot of abandoned string buffers, that need to be collected by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

Basically string immutability problems. Also it provides methods for simpler manipulation of string. Take a look at [Using Stringbuilder Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder is mutable. Strings are not. So any operation on a string creates a new object. In your 2nd sample, 2 objects are created (one on each line). Whereas in the first, only one object is created.

Comment: That's right. But in reality if you don't need to do lots of string operations, String and StringBuilder performs almost equally, and in case of short strings and few appends, simple string works better.